# Proper JSON array interpretation through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Currently able to filter through "teams" and say if it matches x then display everything associated with it. The problem is method searching through hard codes the team category names, but need it to be able to say instead programmatically, for each unique team type sort by that.

As you can see below my solution requires triple statements when it could be covered in just one single object oriented method.

```
$('#jobs-container .jobs-list').append(
  '<div id="teamtop"><span>Legal</span></div>');

for (i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < _data[i].postings.length; j++) {
    var posting = _data[i].postings[j]
    var title = posting.text
    var description = posting.description
    //Making each job description shorter than 250 characters
    var shortDescription = $.trim(description).substring(0, 250)
      .replace('\n', ' ') + "...";
    var location = nullCheck(posting.categories.location);
    var locationCleanString = cleanString(location);
    var commitment = nullCheck(posting.categories.commitment);
    var commitmentCleanString = cleanString(commitment);
    var team = nullCheck(posting.categories.team);
    var teamCleanString = cleanString(team);
    var link = posting.hostedUrl + leverParameter;

    if (team == "Legal") {
      $('#jobs-container .jobs-list').append(
        '<div class="job ' + teamCleanString + ' ' + locationCleanString + ' ' + commitmentCleanString + '">' +
        '<a class="job-title" href="' + link + '"">' + title + '</a>' +
        '</div>'
      );
    }
  }
}

$('#jobs-container .jobs-list').append(
  '<div id="teamtop"><span>Engineering</span></div>');

for (i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < _data[i].postings.length; j++) {
    var posting = _data[i].postings[j]
    var title = posting.text
    var description = posting.description
    //Making each job description shorter than 250 characters
    var shortDescription = $.trim(description).substring(0, 250)
      .replace('\n', ' ') + "...";
    var location = nullCheck(posting.categories.location);
    var locationCleanString = cleanString(location);
    var commitment = nullCheck(posting.categories.commitment);
    var commitmentCleanString = cleanString(commitment);
    var team = nullCheck(posting.categories.team);
    var teamCleanString = cleanString(team);
    var link = posting.hostedUrl + leverParameter;

    if (team == "Engineering") {
      $('#jobs-container .jobs-list').append(
        '<div class="job ' + teamCleanString + ' ' + locationCleanString + ' ' + commitmentCleanString + '">' +
        '<a class="job-title" href="' + link + '"">' + title + '</a>' +
        '</div>'
      );
    }
  }
}

$('#jobs-container .jobs-list').append(
  '<div id="teamtop"><span>Operations</span></div>');

for (i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < _data[i].postings.length; j++) {
    var posting = _data[i].postings[j]
    var title = posting.text
    var description = posting.description
    //Making each job description shorter than 250 characters
    var shortDescription = $.trim(description).substring(0, 250)
      .replace('\n', ' ') + "...";
    var location = nullCheck(posting.categories.location);
    var locationCleanString = cleanString(location);
    var commitment = nullCheck(posting.categories.commitment);
    var commitmentCleanString = cleanString(commitment);
    var team = nullCheck(posting.categories.team);
    var teamCleanString = cleanString(team);
    var link = posting.hostedUrl + leverParameter;

    if (team == "Operations") {
      $('#jobs-container .jobs-list').append(
        '<div class="job ' + teamCleanString + ' ' + locationCleanString + ' ' + commitmentCleanString + '">' +
        '<a class="job-title" href="' + link + '"">' + title + '</a>' +
        '</div>'
      );
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to do a for each around the team but am struggling to output properly:

```
for(i = 0; i < team.length; i++) {
  alert ("output only teams once"+team);
}
```

I have attached more or less the visual concept that is trying to be achieved although the CSS styling is not necessary right now, more so focused on grouping the titles by teams.

[image: sort by team]

So we are getting the correct out put such as

```
Legal
Corporate Associate
Corporate Paralegal
Junior Corporate Associate, Blockchain
Junior Corporate Associate, Emerging Growth
Legal Document Specialist
Regulatory & Compliance Counsel
```

But we are manually matching to legal, just want to filter through each team and see instead.

Vngeener answer repeats team each time, need it to only print out the team one time.

Comment: maybe you should filter the data into appropriate career-category collections before you jerry-rig some complex conditions

Comment: not helpful really

Comment: I don't have an exact solution, but do have a code enhancement suggestion. To make your code run faster and use less memory, declare the variables outside of the loop, then assign the values in the loop. V8 engine will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You do not really need to create "Teamtop" divs manually.
- The for loop you have created should handle that.
- And you do not need the duplicated for loop code for each team heading.
- And in the loop "team" condition is not needed.

The way code is written, that's not utilizing the for-loop capability properly.

Try replacing your code with the code given below (Only once, do not repeat this code for multiple conditions):

```
var teamAdded = [];
for(i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < _data[i].postings.length; j ++) {
        var posting = _data[i].postings[j] 
        var title = posting.text
        var description = posting.description  
        //Making each job description shorter than 250 characters
        var shortDescription = $.trim(description).substring(0, 250)
        .replace('\n', ' ') + "...";
        var location = nullCheck(posting.categories.location);
        var locationCleanString = cleanString(location);
        var commitment = nullCheck(posting.categories.commitment);
        var commitmentCleanString = cleanString(commitment);
        var team = nullCheck(posting.categories.team);
        var teamCleanString = cleanString(team);
        var link = posting.hostedUrl+leverParameter;

        //Add Team top heading dynamically
        if (!teamAdded[team]){
            $('#jobs-container .jobs-list').append(
            '<div id="teamtop"><span>'+ team +'</span></div><div id="team-children"  data-team="'+ team +'"></div>');
            teamAdded[team] = true;
        }
        // team condition was not required here
        // if(team=="Legal"){

        $('[data-team="'+ team +'"]').append(
        '<div class="job '+teamCleanString+' '+locationCleanString+' '+commitmentCleanString+'">' +
        '<a class="job-title" href="'+link+'"">'+title+'</a>' +        
        '</div>'      
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: this repeats team each time, need it to only print out the team one time.

Comment: is there a way to get the team names in a loop and then apply them only once

Comment: updated the logic, to add team heading only once and a new container for each teams sub-links.

Comment: outstanding vngneers